# ReactJS simple login form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, api

I'm building the frontend for a basic CRUD app that will interact with an external API.

I'm attempting to build a simple login form that works by
sending a POST request (username and password) to an external API for validation, getting a response and storing the user information in a session.

We have a list of users already in our API. Using a tool like Postman, I would confirm the user exists when we POST the correct credentials and get a response:

```
POST /api/v1/login

{
  "email": "email@gmail.com",
  "password": "password123"
}

Response:
{
  "data": {
    "team_id": "0987654321",
    "name": "John",
    "email": "email@gmail.com",
    "access_token": "1234567890qwerty"
  }
}
```

I'm new to react, and it's been a while since I've used Javascript, and I don't quite understand how this works. Any help would be appreciated.

Apologies if this info is a little vague.

Comment: https://blog.hellojs.org/fetching-api-data-with-react-js-460fe8bbf8f2

Comment: After you send request from a front-end (with axios for example), its on your api to handle authorization and it has nothing to do with react until the response comes back.

Comment: here is my React login page. hope this helpfull https://github.com/dangminhtruong/havana_client/blob/master/src/components/pages/login/index.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you get the response from your API you should then store any non sensitive information that you may need in your front-end. If you are using something like JWT you can store the token in the localstorage and use `jwt-decode` library for reading it.

```
    fetch(this.email.value, this.password.value)
    .then(res => {
        localStorage.setItem('id_token', res.token) // Store token 
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

It also pretty common in react to have utility or helper file that handles your authorization

/utils/AuthUtility

```
    class AuthService{
        login(email, password) {
            return this.fetch('/login', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    email, 
                    password
                })
            })
              .then(res => {
                if(res.type == 'success'){
                    this.setToken(res.token) // Setting the token in localStorage
                    return Promise.resolve(res); 
                } else {
                    return Promise.reject(res)
                }
            })
        }


  // Other available methods
       setToken(idToken) {
        // Saves user token to localStorage
        localStorage.setItem('id_token', idToken)
       }

      getProfile() {
        // Using jwt-decode npm package to decode the token
        return decode(localStorage.getItem('id_token'); // assuming you have jwt token then use jwt-decode library
      }
    }
```

then in your login component
//components/login.js

```
import AuthUtility from './utils/AuthUtility';

login = (e) => {


    this.Auth.login(this.email.value, this.password.value)
    .then(res => {
        this.props.history.push('/protectedRoute');
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Megs, this was a huge help. I managed to get the data, save it the token in localStorage, and get it working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the very popular http client '[axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)'

Install axios in your react app

```
npm install axios --save
```

Add this code to the click\submit handler function of your login form:

```
axios.post('http://[PATH_HERE]/api/v1/login', {
  "email": "email@gmail.com",
  "password": "password123"
})
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks Gary. axios is a create package, really helped me get this working.

Comment: @sktwentysix happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Creating login component on react using ant design is simple please follow below steps

[image: react login]

To install ant design in react

```
  npm install antd
```

and then install ant icons
npm install --save @ant-design/icons for more info

For more info please [click here](https://androiddhina.blogspot.com/2021/07/how-to-create-react-login-page-using-antd-design.html)